# Performant Background Image Position Animation with Sizing

Tags: css, html

I have a single page web application that does some nice parallax animation when you swipe from panel to panel by doing a calculated CSS transition on `background-position`.

The problem is, the animation is choppy even on an iPhone 5 if I'm sizing the image at all, eg `background-size:cover`

Is there a better way to do this? Should I use an `<img/>` instead that is manually sized and animate the position/margin/whatever instead?

Comment: link to the site or fiddle?

Comment: It think performance drag will be no less whether you use a scaled background-image or a fixed `img` element scaled to the same proportions. I’d suggest you might have better results by providing multiple image sizes on the server, and via media-queries select the most appropriate one (i.e. bigger than viewport height and width) to be displayed as _unscaled_, centered background-image.

Comment: @CBroe Users can pick their own image, we can't control that, unfortunately.

Comment: @ImranBughio Not public yet. I was hoping this was something some had encountered before and had some insight on.